# G Suite Marketplace SDK [Publish] button always greyed out?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-marketplace, google-apps-script-addon

My app is finally published in the G Suite Marketplace.  However, I need to update the banner image as it's blurry and the [Publish] button is always greyed out.  What is missing from this screenshot?

[image: Greyed publish button]

Answer (score 1):

Go into the OAuth Consent Screen, under "APIs and Services" and check that everything is filled in there too. The scopes for example don't always get automatically completed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is a very flimsy answer but after playing with the form, ensuring that I filled in every field, the publish button finally became available.

My guess is that a field labelled as optional is required.

Answer (score 0):

The [instructions to update an Editor add-on](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/update-editor-addons) where last updated on 2020-01-21.

Key things that you should check

1. The scopes in the add-on project, OAuth consent and G Suite Marketplace Config page match.
2. Al the required fields on the G Suite Marketplace Config page are filled (Google made some fields as required that weren't before)

Also you could try using Chrome in incognito mode with all the Chrome extensions disabled.